# Prevent audio from HTML sections / iframes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm loading ads in a website, and some of them play flash files or videos that have sound. Is there a way to prevent them from being able to play any audio?

Comment: I'm the developer of the website, I don't want my visitors to get sound from malicious ads that auto-start it

Comment: You shouldn't load malicious content in the first place. If these sounds are coming from an iframe, there's nothing you can do, except not to load them.

Answer (score 0):

use defaultmuted property of audio/video DOM

```
myAud.defaultMuted=true;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_defaultmuted.asp